# index 0 in the second level javascript arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

can I please know why if a second level entry in a multidimensional javascript Array is returned `undefined` if this level length is equal to `1` ?
**example :**

```
arr = Array(
  Array(1) 
)
```

the following will return this unlikely result : `undefined`, while it's suppose to be `1` (or at least that's what I expect it to be)

```
console.log(arr[0][0])
```

but when i have more than just a record in that level (`length>1`) something like :

```
arr = Array(
  Array(1,2) 
)
```

and then try to : `console.log(arr[0][0])`, it returns `1` this time.
any explanation for this issue or why is this happening would be appreciated
thanks

Comment: Chill man you get down-votes here even if you answer the questions perfectly well but a passerby just hates your indenting or something. That happens all the time. You can not obviate it with new accounts. In JS instantiated arrays are not initiated hence the initial values are undefined. You have to chain an `Array.prototype.fill()` for instance if you need them filled initially.

Comment: There might have been three people who thought that you should have read some documentation before. But it's understandable that this behavior is confusing, which is why using `Array` is generally avoided.

Answer (score 0):

You should consult the [documentation of the `Array` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array):

> **`arrayLength`**
>   If the only argument passed to the `Array` constructor is an integer between 0 and 232-1 (inclusive), this returns a new JavaScript array with `length` set to that number.

`Array(1)` does not create an array with the element `1`, it creates an array of ***length*** 1 with one element: `undefined`.

To have a less ambiguous constructor, use an array literal:

```
[[1]]
```

This is one array which contains one array which contains the value `1`.

Comment: thanks, i will read about this documentation in the link, (thanks for the down vote as well)

Comment: @Simo: Why do you assume that deceze downvoted your question? People who downovted normally don't tend to answer the question... If you downvoted his answer then this is a really bad move from your side. After all the people who answered were actually trying to help you...

Answer (score 0):

**Syntax for Array**

```
[element0, element1, ..., elementN]
new Array(element0, element1[, ...[, elementN]])
new Array(arrayLength)
```

from syntax section on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Its look like if the aregument to Array is one integer, then it's interpreted as length, else it interpreted as content

Which is why you have an empty 2-d array on first case..

Hope this helps.. cheers